# NoReverseMatch at /posts/list/ Reverse for 'post_detail' not found. 'post_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a simple project and I am stuck on this error. I have tried several ways to fix it but non of them work. Maybe you can see and point out my mistake in my code. I am using everything right according to my concept of Django. But I am new that is my concepts are not so strong I guess.

App/urls.py

```
app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/',views.AboutView.as_view(),name ='about'),
    path('new/',views.PostCreateView.as_view(),name= 'create'),
    path('<int:pk>/detail/',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name ='post_detail'),
    path('list/',views.PostListView.as_view(),name ='post_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/remove/',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name ='post_remove'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/',views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),name ='update'),
]
```

App/views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post 

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class='jumbotron'>
<h1>Welcome to grabPublic site</h1>
<p>Title :{{post.title}}</p>

<a class= "btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'posts:post_remove' pk=post.pk %}">del me
</a>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

post_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
    {% for post in post_list %}
    <div class="post">
        <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
        <div class="date">
            <p>
                Published on: {{ post.published|date:"D M Y" }}
            </p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

App/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=("user name"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(('Description'),max_length=250)
    title = models.CharField(('Content Title'), max_length=250)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    image_data = models.ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

App/forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("username","title","description","image_data")

        widgets ={
            'title' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}),
            'description':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'postcontent'}),
        }

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        self.fields['description'].label = 'Description'
```

posts_confirm_delete.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class='jumbotron'>
<h1>Welcome to grabPublic site</h1>
<p>Title :{{post.title}}</p>

<a class= "btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'posts:post_remove' pk=post.pk %}">del me
</a>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not specifying the `context_object_name` in the generic ListView it will be by default `object_list`. So your `post_list` in the template is empty.

You can change the context_object_name like this.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post_list'
```

Also here you are specifying the `app_name` in your urls so your url in the template should be like this.

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'posts:post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you so much It worked. Can you explain me my mistake and the solution you just tell. So next time I dont make mistake like that.

Comment: @AhmedYasin I think I've mentioned your mistake in the answer. What you didn't understand here ?

Comment: One more thing. My list view is working fine now but detail view is still having issue. when i click on publish button i get error on reverse post_detail not found. It suppose to show me post_detail.html template

Comment: where is the `publish` button . I failed to see it in your question.

Comment: In very last in post_form.html template .

Comment: which is the view which handles this form ?

Comment: create view handles this form

Comment: change your `get_absoulte_url` in your model. `return reverse("posts:post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})`

Comment: Nice! Brother You just nailed it thank You so much. I feel so disappoint from myself. How silly mistakes i am making .Well can you tell me what dose get_absolute function do ?

Comment: Glad it worked.If you are using the generic `CreateView` and haven't specified the `success_url` then it will by default look for the `absolute_url` and redirect to this url. You can look more on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: If you dont mind can you tell me one more thing ? in this same code i am having issue with delete view. when i click on delete del me button it shows an error:NoReverseMatch at /posts/27/remove/

Reverse for 'posts/post_list' not found. 'posts/post_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: I already said it in the answer. You need to specify the`app_name` in your url if you are using it.`success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:post_list')`

Comment: Oky Thank You Now i got it completely thank you so much.

Comment: i have asked new question can you answer that question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63736357/integrityerror-at-profiles-profile-not-null-constraint-failed-profiles-userpr